# Apollo Mutation - UI not updated after useMutation update

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

Background: always able to make Apollo store cache updated, but not UI

Question:

1. what's the reason that makes the UI updated or not?
2. what's the right way to pass the data object in update?

"react": "~16.9.0"

"@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3"

Both UI and cache updated codes in my project:

```
update: (store, { data: { newPhoto } }) => {
  const { bookInfo } = store.readQuery({ query: GET_BOOK_BY_ID, variables: { bookId } });
  bookInfo.photos = [...bookInfo.photos, newPhoto];

  store.writeQuery({ 
      query: GET_BOOK_BY_ID, 
      variables: { bookId },
      data: {
          bookInfo
      }
  });
}
```

In this line: `bookInfo.photos = [...bookInfo.photos, newPhoto];`, the bookInfo object is amended directly and just passed back to `writeQuery`'s `data`

This doesn't look okay to me as I saw people saying it needs to be "immutable" or "passing new object", etc.

Comment: I think, there may be an issue on your Query part inside the render function of your component or so. Please share your code for Query part, especially how & which variables you the to useQuery. The variables part should be exactly same with what you mutate

Comment: Hi @TrueEye! thanks for the comment. I have figured the issue because I didn't edit the data in an immutable fashion!
People who experience the same thing, definitely go to check out https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/4543. By applying the freezeResults & assumeImmutableResults into the Apollo Client will help detect the issue.

Answer (score 2):

if you experience the same thing, please check following list:

1. go to check out https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/4543. By applying the `freezeResults` & `assumeImmutableResults` into the `ApolloClient` will help detect the issue. For my case, the issue actually occurs inside the parent component, which I mutated the Apollo store objects, instead of the component that calling `client.writeQuery`, which is generally hard for others to notice too, in my opinion.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ...,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    freezeResults: true, // new
  }),
  assumeImmutableResults: true, // new
});
```

2. Ensure you mutate the data in an immutable fashion. (i.e. Apollo store object hasn't been changed until the end of update) https://github.com/immerjs/immer definitely helps to keep your change in immutable fashion. I used this to mutate my nested object and it's working so well.
3. Try to use `client` returned from the `useMutation`, then you get `client.writeQuery` to do the update. Although I'm not sure about this point, a lot of people spreading this message, probably help in some cases.

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import produce from "immer";

const [mutate, { client }] = useMutation(MUTATION_GQL);

const submit = () => {
    mutate({
        variables: { inputs },
        update: (store, { data: { response }) => {
            // get existing cache returned from the query
            const cache = store.readQuery({ query: QUERY_GQL, variables: { id } });

            // manipulate the cache in immutable fashion
            const data = produce(cache, draftCache => {
                draftCache.title = "new title";
                draftCache.approval = response;
            });

            // write the cache back to that query
            // REMEMBER the variables inside writeQuery too!
            client.writeQuery({
                query: QUERY_GQL,
                variables: { id },
                data,
            });
        }
    })
}
```

4. Try to use `useQuery` to read the data from `ApolloClient` instead of `readQuery` so you will get the updated cache from Apollo's store